# Bootstrap Select Js Large İ not Search

Tags: javascript, select, search, drop-down-menu, live

im using bootstrap select on my website. I have a problem, Large İ not search (when i type in lowercase) :(

http://jsfiddle.net/2qzv5yn1/

I am using standard js functions. So I didn't add js.

```
<select name="nereden" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search-style="startsWith" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" data-size="5">
<option value="">{{ trans('nav.from') }}</option>
<option value="{{$istasyon->istasyonId}}-{{$istasyon->istasyonAdi}}">İstanbul</option>
<option value="{{$istasyon->istasyonId}}-{{$istasyon->istasyonAdi}}">Ankara</option>
<option value="{{$istasyon->istasyonId}}-{{$istasyon->istasyonAdi}}">Çankırı</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise on your problem ? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzjoxu16/) As you can see in the link, this is working, when I type i in lowercase, İstanbul is selected. Maybe I didn't uderstand your problem.

Comment: Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/2b4fs5me/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2qzv5yn1/

When I want to find Istanbul, I do not find the small letter i. It only comes out when İ write the big I letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the character **İ** is similar to a capital **I**, it's not the exact same character. You need to set `liveSearchNormalize` to `true` to allow for accent-insensitive searching, either via

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ liveSearchNormalize: true });
```

or by adding `data-live-search-normalize="true"` to your select element. The liveSearchNormalize feature was expanded/improved in v1.13.4, so you'll need to use at least that version.

See a preview of it working with v1.13.8 here https://plnkr.co/edit/kRDYg2wNyoOqFeUIOhNT?p=preview.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your help